# Skeleton CSS classes grids

Tags: css, grid-system, skeleton-code

I'm creating a grid system in wordpress using Skeleton.css

The tutorial shows the following markup for the header, here you can see the logo has has a 3 classes, - five columns and clearfix

```
   <header>
        <div class="five columns clearfix">
    get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.svg"></a>
        </div>
    </header>
```

But when I look at the skellton css I cannot see a class of 'five' So i changed it to .five.columns  But his make no difference, I i create a border around the class .five.columns, it does not show up am I missing something obvious?

```
  .one.column,
  .one.columns                    { width: 4.66666666667%; }
  .two.columns                    { width: 13.3333333333%; }
  .three.columns                  { width: 22%;            }
  .four.columns                   { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .five.columns                   { width: 39.3333333333%; }
  .six.columns                    { width: 48%;            }
  .seven.columns                  { width: 56.6666666667%; }
  .eight.columns                  { width: 65.3333333333%; }
  .nine.columns                   { width: 74.0%;          }
  .ten.columns                    { width: 82.6666666667%; }
  .eleven.columns                 { width: 91.3333333333%; }
  .twelve.columns                 { width: 100%; margin-left: 0; }

  .one-third.column               { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .two-thirds.column              { width: 65.3333333333%; }

  .one-half.column                { width: 48%; }

  /* Offsets */
  .offset-by-one.column,
  .offset-by-one.columns          { margin-left: 8.66666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two.column,
  .offset-by-two.columns          { margin-left: 17.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-three.column,
  .offset-by-three.columns        { margin-left: 26%;            }
  .offset-by-four.column,
  .offset-by-four.columns         { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-five.column,
  .offset-by-five.columns         { margin-left: 43.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-six.column,
  .offset-by-six.columns          { margin-left: 52%;            }
  .offset-by-seven.column,
  .offset-by-seven.columns        { margin-left: 60.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eight.column,
  .offset-by-eight.columns        { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-nine.column,
  .offset-by-nine.columns         { margin-left: 78.0%;          }
  .offset-by-ten.column,
  .offset-by-ten.columns          { margin-left: 86.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eleven.column,
  .offset-by-eleven.columns       { margin-left: 95.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-third.column,
  .offset-by-one-third.columns    { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two-thirds.column,
  .offset-by-two-thirds.columns   { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-half.column,
  .offset-by-one-half.columns     { margin-left: 52%; }

}

/* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) {}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with some styling for height and color to make it obvious. Is your div 0px height? Check it with your developer tools in the browser - [Chrome Developer Tools website](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

https://jsfiddle.net/p1w61hmt/.

```
<header style="height: 100px; background: green;">
    <div class="five columns clearfix" style="height: 100%;">
    </div>
</header>

.five.columns { width: 39.3333333333%; }
.columns { background: red; }
```

Its probably some pasting errors but your HTML is not valid and your css looks like an incomplete snippet.